# How do I consume a webservice running on localhost in a project located on a vm?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-services, web-reference

I am running a webservice on my development box and I need to test that webservice in a virtual machine that is running on the host(aka the development box).  The webservice on the dev box is running at:

`http://localhost:8100/ws_name.asmx`.

From the VM I have unsuccessfully tried things like:

`http://host_machine_ip/ws_name.asmx`

`http://host_machine_ip:8100/ws_name.asmx`

`//host_machine_ip/ws_name.asmx`

`//host_machine_ip:8100/ws_name.asmx`

Is it possible to test this webservice from my VM?

Comment: This is not a programming problem - it's a network configuration problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running this service in the Visual Studio's built-in web server bear in mind that this server doesn't accept remote connections. So you will need to host it in IIS.